# add views to a horizontal linearlayout next and below eachother dynamically

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have a recyclerview in which i have to show a header and description. The descrtiption consists of n number of items(TextViews) that are to be added dynamically next to each other as shown in image. However if items width is greater than screen width it should go to next line.

Currently I have a horizontal linear layout and I want to add new item(TextView) on new line if there isnt enough room for it.My implementation gives below image error. I want the output to be like image 2

How do I implement it? Are there better ways to do this.

Is there a way to check TextViews screen width without adding view to hirarchy?

[image: Actual output]

[image: Expected output]

Comment: if you can use library, then there are many, 
try googling TagView

Answer (score 0):

1) create a linearlayout in your xml layout like below :

```
<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llKeyword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            </LinearLayout>
```

2) now create one xml layout **view_textview.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tvName"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:text="sadfjkhsdf"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
```

3) now create methods like below :

```
void setKeywords(LinearLayout llKeyword, List<String> keywords) {

        llKeyword.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        llKeyword.removeAllViews();
        List<String> keywordsList = keywords;

        int width = 0;
        LinearLayout parent = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < keywordsList.size(); i++) {

            if (width == 0) {
                parent = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
                parent.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                parent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                parent.setPadding(15, 0, 15, 0);
                measureView(parent);
            }

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            params.setMargins(0, 5, 15, 5);

            View someLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(
                    R.layout.view_textview, null);
            final TextView tvKeyword = (TextView) someLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            tvKeyword.setText(keywordsList.get(i));
            //tvKeyword.setText(R.string.txt_period_location);
            tvKeyword.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_stroke_white));
            tvKeyword.setLayoutParams(params);

            measureView(tvKeyword);

            width += tvKeyword.getMeasuredWidth() + 5;

            Log.e("", "textview width " + tvKeyword.getMeasuredWidth()
                    + " width " + width);
            if (width < getWidth())
                parent.addView(tvKeyword);
            else {
                llKeyword.addView(parent);
                width = 0;
                parent = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
                parent.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                parent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                measureView(parent);

                width += tvKeyword.getMeasuredWidth();
                parent.addView(tvKeyword);
            }

            if (i == keywordsList.size() - 1)
                llKeyword.addView(parent);
        }

    }

    protected int getWidth() {
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(
                Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        Log.e("", "Width " + display.getWidth());
        return display.getWidth() - 80;
    }

    protected void measureView(View view) {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
        int childWidth = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(0, view.getPaddingLeft()
                + view.getPaddingRight(), params.width);
        int childHeight = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(0,
                view.getPaddingBottom() + view.getPaddingTop(), params.height);
        view.measure(childWidth, childHeight);
    }
```

4) now use above method like below :

```
LinearLayout llKeyword = findViewById(R.id.llKeyword);//find linear layout

 setKeywords(llKeyword, keywords);// call this method
```

5) edit : for making background with colorful. make one drawable file **btn_bgsolid_blue.xml** add below drawable in background of **view_textviews.xml** file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#47bee6"></solid>
    <corners android:radius="15dp"></corners>
</shape>
```